# c - undefined behavior when changing element of char array

Tags: c

Line 9 of the below code generates undefined behavior. Is this due to the fact that `title1[]` is outside of `main()` and is global? Or is it because something else that I'm missing?

```
1. char title1[]="The Name of the Rose";
2. Book book1={title1,900,0};
3. int main(){
4.   Book book2={"Foucault's Pendulum",1000,0};
5.   Book* book3=(Book*)malloc(sizeof(Book));
6.   *book3=book2;
7.   book1.next=&book2;
8.   book2.next=book3;
9.   book1.title[0]='B';
10.  book2.title[0]='A';
11.  {
12.    Book list[2];
13.    list[0]=book1;
14.    list[1]=book2;
15.    list[1].next->next=&book2;
16.    {
17.      Book* p=&list[0];
18.      while (p!=0) {
19.        p=p->next;
20.    }
21.  }
22. return 0;
23.}
```

EDIT:

Added the Book definition:

```
‫;‪struct Book‬‬
‪typedef struct Book‬ {
‫;‪  char* title‬‬
  int pages;‬‬
‫;‪  struct Book* next‬‬
‫;‪} Book‬‬
```

Comment: Could you add the definition of the `Book` class?

Comment: It's undefined because you're modifying a string literal constant (not a copy of it).

Comment: is the first element in the book structure is a pointer ?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Apparently, its first element is a pointer to char and that's all you need to know about it.

Comment: @JanDvorak Are you sure?  `book1.title` is a reference to the character array `title1`, so unless the `title` element of the `Book` class is const-qualified (in which case, the code should not compile), there shouldn't be a problem.  Now, line 10 and assigning to `book2.title` which is a reference to a string literal; that would be undefined behaviour.  And this is C; C does not have 'constructors'.

Comment: Duplicate hundreds of times over.  [Modifying String Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal) is just one example.

Comment: Please try to create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) before posting.  It'll help you find and fix your bugs without having to ask duplicate questions here.

Comment: @PhilipKendall added definition.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the line with the UB is actually line 10, which modifies the string in the second book, not the first entry - which is perfectly allowed to do. Probably just a counting error on line numbers, I expect.

Comment: How do you know that line 9 gives undefined behavior?

Comment: ...For that matter, what UB are you observing?  How can you call it UB without knowing that what you're doing is wrong, or else observing a variety of strange behaviors that you're attributing to UB?

Comment: @DavidGrayson it was the TA answer to this question. phonetagger sometimes i get seg fault, other times it runs for ever

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, line 9 is not undefined behavior. It writes to this array:

```
char title1[]="The Name of the Rose";
```

which is not a string literal (but initialized by one). Such a plain array can be modified to your liking. It would have been different if you would have declared it like this:

```
char *title1="The Name of the Rose";
```

The undefined behavior is in line 10, here you are writing into a string literal, which is not allowed.

BTW, when asking a question here, please cook it down to a minimal example that shows your point. Most of the code you posted is completely useless for your question.

Comment: So it's fine to change elements of an array that resides in the global code? Isn't this memory read only?

Comment: Why should it be read-only? It would only be read-only if you'd declare it with a `const`-qualifier. String *literals* are different from that, they aren't objects that you are supposed to change.

Comment: I think one should even say "they are objects you are **not** supposed to change".

Comment: @Daniel, yes, should have said that.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify a string literal in line 10.

Comment: `char title1[]` is an array so i'm not trying to modify a string literal

Comment: @Tom It's line 10 that invokes UB through attempting to modify a string literal, as Jonathan Leffler pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs on line 10, because a string literal is a constant and therefore read only. Any write on it will cause an error.