# Issue with small example that uses strcpy in Xcode

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I'm trying to understand this code below but Xcode is giving me an error at the 2nd to last line saying "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

```
char string1[4] = "abc";
char string2[4] = "def";

printf("%s \n%s\n", string1, string2);

strcpy(string1, string1+1); // Xcode points here, "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

printf("%s \n%s", string1, string2);
```

What's going on ? I expected it to print

```
abc
def
bc
def
```

but it obviously stops halfway through.

Answer (score 3):

Quoted from strcpy documentation: *The source and destination strings should not overlap, as the behavior is undefined.*

Your source and destination overlap.

Use memmove() for overlapping data instead.

Comment: Isn't the fact that [this is modifying a literal string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal) also important?

Comment: It's not modifying a string literal.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: good thing I phrased it as a question then ;-) You are correct, as explained in the very link I pointed to.