# Xamarin ndk get string from c function as return value

Tags: c#, android, c, android-ndk, xamarin

My return char function is not working. Others working fine, can someone help me with how to get string from C function as return value?

I've tried to search for it, but couldn't found solution.

This is my cpp code

```
#include <android/log.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

extern "C" void bar_init ()
{
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "*jonp*", "bar_init");

}

extern "C" int getMyName(int recept){
    return recept;
}


extern "C" void PrintMyString(char const * chars){

    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "*jonp*", chars);
}

extern "C" char* ReturnMyChar (char *chars){

strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')");
__android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "*jonp*", chars);
return chars;
}
```

And my C# code

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace NativeTest
{
    [Activity (Label = "NativeTest", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {

        [DllImport ("bar.so")]
        static extern void bar_init();
        [DllImport ("bar.so")]
        static extern int getMyName(int test);
        [DllImport ("bar.so")]
        static extern void PrintMyString (string myname);
        [DllImport ("bar.so")]
        static extern string ReturnMyChar(string mychar);
        int count = 1;

        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate (bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);
            Console.WriteLine ("PREPARING");
            bar_init ();
            int mybytes = getMyName (10);
            PrintMyString ("Hello World");
            Console.WriteLine ("WORKING:{0}",mybytes);
            //string myValue = "hello";
            string bytes = ReturnMyChar ("h");
            //Console.WriteLine (myValue);
            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it
            Button button = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.myButton);

            button.Click += delegate {
                button.Text = string.Format ("{0} clicks!", count++);
            };
        }

        static byte[] GetBytes(string str)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[str.Length * sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(str.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            return bytes;
        }

        static string GetString(byte[] bytes)
        {
            char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length / sizeof(char)];
            System.Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, chars, 0, bytes.Length);
            return new string(chars);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my log :

```
 [Resources] Preloaded drawable resource #0x1080093 (android:drawable/sym_def_app_icon) that varies with configuration!!
[Mono] DllImport attempting to load: '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
[Mono] DllImport loaded library '/system/lib/liblog.so'.
[Mono] DllImport searching in: '/system/lib/liblog.so' ('/system/lib/liblog.so').
[Mono] Searching for '__android_log_print'.
[Mono] Probing '__android_log_print'.
[Mono] Found as '__android_log_print'.
PREPARING
[*jonp*] bar_init
[*jonp*] Hello World
WORKING:10
[*jonp*] INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')
[libc] invalid address or address of corrupt block 0xb7a8eee8 passed to dlfree
[mono-rt] Stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt]   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
```

Found solution

C code

```
extern "C" char* ReturnMyChar (){

    int len=strlen("INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')")+1;
    char *chars=(char*) malloc(len);
    memset(chars,0,len);
    strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')");
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "*jonp*", chars);
    return chars;
}
```

C# code

```
[DllImport ("bar.so")]
        static extern IntPtr ReturnMyChar();

.....

IntPtr bytes = ReturnMyChar ();
            Console.WriteLine ("result string :"+Marshal.PtrToStringAuto(bytes));
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in a variable to your function instead of a constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my assumption you are in trouble because of [modifying string literal in `C`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal)

from your `C#` code you have called

```
string bytes = ReturnMyChar ("h");
```

And in `C` you have receive function

```
extern "C" char* ReturnMyChar (char *chars){..}
```

So here argument becomes `char *chars="h"` which is constant string and compiler put it in read only memory. So modifying it cause Undefined behaviour. here

```
strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')");
```

you have write data in string literal which cause you issues.

Now to overcome this you have to allocate memory in function and return that char array.

Also `strcpy` overwrite your previous buffer with current one. So there is no meaning of passing string in function.

```
 string bytes = ReturnMyChar ("h");//OP can you tell me 
                                   // what is purpose of passing "h"?
```

Solution but without testing
In `C` code

```
extern "C" char* ReturnMyChar ()
{
    int len=strlen("INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')")+1;
    char *chars=malloc(len);
    memset(chars,0,len);
    strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')");
    __android_log_print (ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "*jonp*", chars);
    return chars;
}
```

And from `C#` you can call like

```
 string bytes = ReturnMyChar ();
```

Comment: This looks fine. I'm no c++ programmer so I just tried to help with what I could, but your answer is quite good and also right I think

Comment: @DatRid Ok and your answer also solve one OP issue which indeed important to resolve first.That's why already given you +1 for it.

Comment: tnx for answer little bit wrong but it helped me lot

Comment: @munkh can you point out where is wrong so i will update answer?

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '");
```

to:

```
strcpy( chars, "INSERT INTO test (nazwa, liczba) VALUES ('nowy wpis', '')");
```

Otherwise it is an wrong SQL-Statement.

You need to close the bracket for `VALUES` again!
Also a single `'` doesn't work.

Comment: its not about SQL i can't get string from c function as return value so i can't use my query anyway  Tnx for answer

Comment: Sure? Try to correct the SQL, and then show the error please. Because at the moment the problem seems to me the SQL-Statement. And if the SQL-Statement in the C-code fails, it will break and won't return you a value.