# Can we change string characters pointed by pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

Suppose

```
char* p = "alisha";
```

Can we change the value of string or can we make pointer point somewhere else?

In which scenarios we can and we can't change the string. Kindly explain with examples.

Comment: You can't modify a string literal.

Comment: It's better for you to do your homework yourself

Comment: But through pointers we can change, right?

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal)

Comment: He probably wanted to ask: **Can we change characters in string pointed by pointer?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String literals are stored in memory that is *read-only*, so you **can't** change it.

If you don't want the string to be changed during the program, it is better to do

```
char const *p = "alisha";
```

Then, when you try to change the string, your program will *not* crash with segmentation fault, it will arise a *compiler error* (which is much better).

Your questions can be easily answered by writing a very basic and simple program, go ahead and try it, you'll better understand things by writing code.

Comment: And if we have some requirement , we need to change?

Comment: @alisha Change what?

Comment: Suppose we want to change "his" to "her"

Answer (score 0):

You can change what it points to. E.g.,

```
char *p="cats";
printf("%s\n",p); //prints "cats"
p="bats";
printf("%s\n",p); //prints "bats"
```

But, if you want to change the letters in "cats" like you would manipulate an array, then you have to use an array, like this:

```
char p[]="cats";
```

which gives you an array of characters {'c','a','t','s','\0'}, which you can manipulate like:

```
p[0]='b';
```

or whatever

Comment: Now cats and bats are on same memory address or different

Comment: I believe you can print the memory address and see for yourself

Comment: use printf("%p\n",p);

Answer (score 0):

You can change what string p is pointing to.

```
char *p;
p = "his";
printf("%s\n", p);
p = "her";
printf("%s\n", p);
```

will print

```
his
her
```