# Duplicating strings passed to functions as parameters in C

Tags: c, string, struct, strdup

I couldn't think of a proper title to my question so here it goes. I am trying to learn C and the following code is from the tutorial I am following.

```
struct Person {
    char *name;
    int age;
    int height;
    int weight;
};

struct Person *Person_create(char *name, int age, int height, int weight){
    struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
    assert(who != NULL);

    who->name = strdup(name);
    who->age = age;
    who->height = height;
    who->weight = weight;

    return who;
}

void Person_destroy(struct Person *who){
    assert(who != NULL);

    free(who->name);
    free(who);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    struct Person *joe = Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);

    ........
```

My question is in `Person_create` function why are we duplicating `name` to a new memory location for `who->name` . Why can't we just make `who->name` point to the same location provided by the `*name` supplied to the function.
Also if we directly assigned the address of `*name` to `who->name` do we have to free it in `Person_destroy`.

Comment: suppose if you did `who->name = name` then you con't modify `who->name` latter as function argument `name` points to string literal. as @al-Acme also explained in his answer,

Comment: How is Person_create() called. Where is parameter `name` passed from? How is it created?

Comment: Thank you everyone for answers and comments..

Comment: Just a suggestion: You might want to improve your question title a bit. It doesn't actually reflect your question.

Comment: @zoska It is already there. `Person_create("Joe Alex", 32, 64, 140);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why can't we just make who->name point to the same location provided by the *name supplied to the function.

For me this `who->name = strdup(name);` is better than this `who->name = name;` if i know i will modify the string pointed by `name` later somewhere.

So you might as well do this:

```
who->name = name;
```

However a string literal like `"Joe Alex"` is in a read-only location - so if you wanted to do something like this (*later* in some part of your code):

```
who->name[3] = 'x';
```

you would get segmentation fault. So if you want to modify it you would like to `malloc` some *writable* space from heap which `strdup` does for you.

You might want to have a look at: [Modifying String Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal)

Answer (score -2):

The char array `*name` is not an allocated array, that means if you leave your function scope, this array is not usable anymore. So the tutorial copies it in order to do operations later on this variable.
Moreover, if you directly assigned your variable `*name` to `who->name` you must not free it because it was not returned by malloc.

Comment: This is not true, since the value of `name` can still be used. Just any reference to the variable will be invalid, not it's value.

Comment: @PhilippMurry The bit about not freeing `who->name` if it was directly assigned with address of `name` is true right?. As mentioned in @al-Acme's answer the original `name` is not on the heap.

Comment: If it's not on the heap, then that's true. As a rule of thumb: For each call to malloc/calloc, there must be one call to free. Not more and not less. So if it's not on the heap, there was never a call to malloc/calloc, and therefore no call to free is needed.