# Is it applicable to pass pointer to character (after assigning string to it) to method and modify this string after without using array and why not?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I want to pass string to a c function using pointer to char and modify it and it gave me segmentation fault. I don't know why ? 
Note*: I know I can pass the string to array of character will solve the problem

I tried to pass it to array of character and pass to function the name of array and it works , but I need to know what the problem of passing the pointer to character.

```
void convertToLowerCase(char* str){

    int i=0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(str[i]>='A'&& str[i]<='Z'){
            str[i]+=32;
        }
        i++;
    }
}

int main(void){

    char *str = "AHMEDROSHDY";
    convertToLowerCase(str);
}
```

I expect the output str to be "ahmedroshdy", but the actual output segmentation fault

Comment: string literal.

Comment: @gsamaras how can you clarify more ,this is not const char* ?

Comment: @xing I know that but I need to know why when I use char str* , it give this error .. what happens in memory  and why this is consider wrong need to understand ?

Comment: The string literal will still be in read-only memory (not necessarily but practically always) so you can’t change it.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen why str become in read-only , it became as const char* str and I didn't do that to become read-only can you clarify more pls ?

Comment: @xing ok but why this happened it is not const char * str. and I can do str[0]= any character. right ?

Comment: @xing that is right . the str[0] = 'a'; is not possible because it seems the char* is read-only so any char* is just read-only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (you had `char str*` which is a syntax error, fixed that):

```
char *str = "AHMEDROSHDY";
```

is a pointer to a **string literal**, thus it cannot be modified, since it is stored in *read-only* memory.

You modify it here `str[i]+=32;`, which is not allowed.

Use an array instead, as @xing suggested, i.e. `char str[] = "AHMEDROSHDY";`.

Comment: you means this as const char* str ? I can't get why this happens ?

Comment: Because it stored in read-only memory @ahmedroshdy. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal) for more.

Comment: @xing it is [platform-specific](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go) where string literals are stored.

Comment: @gsamaras it is compiler dependent or what ? that means this value allocated in memory after linkage (linker process) I mean not in compile time right ? but this why happen ?

Comment: Read the link @ahmedroshdy I answered with to xing. Because this is how the language is designed. Hope that helps! :)

Comment: @gsamaras yes it is helpful also [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal) , sorry for asking more but I like to deep understand this. anyway to enclose this we can say that any pointer to character for any platform it must be in data segment and this is how the language designed right ?.. thanks

Comment: Any string literal is designed by the language to be not modifiable @ahmedroshdy.

Comment: Any string literal is designed by the language to be not modifiable @ahmedroshdy. BTW, it would be nice to accept an answer from the two posted here, since both are correct.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise:

`char *str = "AHMEDROSHDY";`

'str` is a pointer to the string literal. String literals in C are not modifacable

in the C standard:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances: ...
>
> - The program attempts to modify a string literal