# getting core dumped error when trying to use strcpy

Tags: c

First of all i would like to know why exactly case 1 gives me core dump error.
secondly I want to understand if my mindset is correct.

So i created 2 cases, in the first case when i execute, i get a core dumped message and the program exits.

The other case runs and i see the result.

```
    //case 1
    //'word' is not initialized properly,or by using malloc or calloc
    //as a result 'word' content will not change when you i use strcpy to copy over it
    char * word = "hello";
    printf("%s\n",word);
    strcpy(word,"world");
    printf("%s\n",word);

    //case 2
    //this case works because I create a static variable word with size 20
    //and everytime I change it, The compiler knows where to find it in the stack.
    char  word[20] = "";
    char * word2 = "yolo";
    strcpy(word,"hello");

    printf("%s\n",word); //prints hello as expected
    strcpy(word,word2); //copies yolo to word
    printf("%s\n",word); // prints yolo
   //hence strcpy does not change the reference
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17507772/9072753

Comment: Turn on all compiler warnings

Comment: @Zaffy OP isn't trying to diagnose something, he's just trying to understand why one piece of code crashes and the other one doesn't.

Comment: What does "//hence strcpy does not change the reference" mean? `strcpy` changes the content of the array, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @tay10r I am aware of that and, warnings would definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> //case 1
>
> 'word' is not initialized properly,or by using malloc or calloc

The `word` pointer is properly initialized with the address of the first character of a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal) `"helllo"`.

> as a result 'word' content will not change when you i use strcpy to copy over it

As a result, `word` pointer points to **not modifiable** memory and that memory can't be modified. Modifying the content of the memory where `word` points to results in [undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior) of your program.

> strcpy(word,"world")

Modifies the memory where the pointer `word` points to. This results in undefined behavior according to C. `strcpy` tries to write to a "read-only" memory or to a memory the system is not allowing the program to write to - on most systems this results in a [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault), which is literally a failure condition associated with accessing a restricted memory area.

> //case 2
>
> this case works because I create a static variable word with size 20

The [static](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) keyword is (most commonly) associated in C with creating variables with static storage duration - this is not important here. The definition `char word[20]` tells the compiler to allocate storage for 20 `char`s. Such definition creates storage that can be modified. It does not matter if such declaration is used with the keyword `static` or not, the storage is accessible via `word` is modifiable.

> and everytime I change it, The compiler knows where to find it in the stack.

Hm... The compiler will most probably always know where to find it on the stack - the address of `word` array - ie. `&word` - does not change. In `strcpy(word,"hello");` you change the content of the array, the memory allocated with `word` array, not the array location.

Comment: So what i understand is, in the second case: "hello" is written somewhere in the stack and the first cell of the array word will point to the first cell of array "hello". is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

With `char * word = "hello";` you have defined a string as a pointer to a char, initialised by a string literal. String literals are stored in a read only section of memory and are effectively constant.

The value is stored in a read-only section in the binary file and cannot be modified. If you compile to an assembly file (use the -S compiler option in gcc), you can see the string literals in the .rodata section. In this context, rodata means “read-only data”.

Though the string literal is read-only, you can modify your `char *` by pointing it to a different string literal:

```
char *word = "hello";
// Redefine the char pointer
word = "world";
```

This re-assignment is OK - you will see both string literals in your assembly file. In this case you can't use `strcpy()` to copy into `word` because it is immutable.

In case 2, you declare your string as a character array `char word[20]`. You are declaring an empty "string" (really a char array) with space for 20 characters. Copying `word2` (a string literal) into `word` works because in this case `word` was declared as a character array and is therefore mutable.