# why does passing C string into function as char* cause runtime error (but passing C string defined as char[] is ok)?

Tags: c, string

I have a simple C program as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void convertToUpperCase(char* sPtr);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char myString[] = "cHaRacTerS aND $32.95";
    char* anotherString = "cHaRacTerS aND $32.95";
    
    convertToUpperCase(myString); // THIS IS OK!
    convertToUpperCase(anotherString); // THIS CAUSES RUNTIME ERROR 
                                       // (ie. build success but run fail)!

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void convertToUpperCase(char* sPtr) {
    while (*sPtr != '\0') { // current character is not null (ie. end of string).
        *sPtr = toupper(*sPtr); // turns valid characters into upper case
        ++sPtr; // point to next character within the string.
    }
}
```

It seems like passing `anotherString` into the function that expects a `char*` is the problem. From my understanding, both `myString` and `anotherString` are `char*` in C.

It seems to me the problem is how they are defined. For `myString` I defined it as an array of characters with a null terminator at the end. For `anotherString` it is a character pointer to a string literal somewhere.

But I can't figure out why the way they are defined matters in this situation.

Thanks in advance :)

edit: used specific terms as suggested by answers.

Comment: also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because when you declare a literal, it is read only.

```
char myString[] = "cHaRacTerS aND $32.95"; // readwrite memory
char* anotherString = "cHaRacTerS aND $32.95"; // placed in readonly memory
```

Edit: to clarify, it is not only read-only, it is UB to write to a string literal. Thanks for that comment, @chux-reinstate-monica

Comment: Detail: Writing to a _string literal_ is UB.  It might "work", might not.  Best to not attempt to write.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, agreed.