# How do I change char from 2D array referenced with pointer of pointer

Tags: c, pointers

In the bellow example, I would like to change some of the characters of my 2D array using standard "array[x][y]" syntax, I have tried several syntax such has *(world[0][1]), ... but always getting error Syntax or segmentation fault.

```
char *map[] = { "12345\0",
                "67890\0"
              };

void change( char **world) {

   world[0][1] = 'X';   // <-- I want to replace character 2 of line 1 (2) by char 'X'

}

void main() {

    printf("line=%s\n",map[0]);
    printf("char=%c\n",map[0][1]);
    change(map);
    printf("now line is =%s\n",map[0]);

}
```

resulting

```
$ ./a.out
line=12345
line=2
Segmentation fault
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `\0` in `"12345\0"` is redundant.

Comment: String literals are constant and can't be modified.

Comment: Besides @JohnnyMopp's point,  assuming your strings are always `7` `char`acters, you should change `char **world` to `char world[][7]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Modifying String Literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal)

Answer (score 1):

## The Problem

you can't use `arr[y][x]` syntax, because

```c
void foo(char **bar) {
   (char[H][W)bar; // ILLEGAL
}
```

is illegal, you can't turn a `char **` into a `char [][]`, you either have to use a different syntax or pass map not as a pointer, but as an array(and change the type of map)

## **SOLUTIONS**

What you can do is take map as a `char [][]`

```c
// note that you have to change from char *map[] to this
char map[H][W] = ...;

map[y][x] = '9';
```

### OR

With a pointer to a multi-dimentional, you can get the element at `n`, with something like:

```c
#define W 5 // width
#define H 2 // height
char *arr[H][W] = { "1234\0", "5678\0" };

// start is &arr[0][0]
void changeAt(char *start, int n, char x) {
   // treat arr as a 1 dimentional array
   *(start + (n / W) + (n % W)) = x;
}

// start is &arr[0][0]
void changeXY(char *start, int x, int y, char n) {
   *(start + (y / W) + x) = n;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C language, 2D arrays and arrays of pointers are different animals.

```
char *map[] = { "12345\0",
                "67890\0"
              };
```

declares an array of 2 char pointers, both pointing to non modifiable string literals.

You can *initialize* non const char arrays from a literal and then use them in your array of pointers:

```
char arr1[] = "12345\0"; // 7 chars with 2 terminating null characters
char arr2[] = "64789\0"; // id.
char *map[] = {arr1, arr2};
```

Alternatively, you can declare a true 2D array (all rows have same size) and initialize it:

```
char map[][7] = {"12345", "6789"};
```