# getting "Segmentation fault (core dumped) error and i don't know why

Tags: arrays, c, loops, cs50, string-literals

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    string a = "bob";
    string b = "steve'";
    for (int c = 0, n = strlen(b); c < n; c++)
    {
        a[c] = b[c];
        if (a[c] == '\0')
        {
            a[c+1] = '\0';
            a[c] = b[c];
        }
        if (b[c] == '\0')
        {
            a[c] = '\0';
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

The error happens at the line that says a[c] = b[c] first, or the 12th line of code. The point of the code is to try and change string a to string b. However, it seems that I cant make two characters of arrays equal. Is there some way this is possible?

To make the those strings the same, I simply tried making their characters equal. It resulted in a Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Comment: I believe in cs50 `string` is just a `typedef char*`, meaning that `"bob"` and `"steve"` are string literals, and [modifying string literals is undefined behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal). Instead, try `char a[] = "bob";`, etc.

Comment: Futhermore, you're overwriting the bounds of `a` by looping on `strlen(b)`. Can do something like `char a[32] = "bob"` to add more space.

Comment: That typedef is incredibly misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters it seems there is a typo

```
"steve'"
      ^^
```

Nevertheless pointers `a` and `b` declared like

```
string a = "bob";
string b = "steve'";
```

where the name `string` is an alias for the type `char *` point to string literals `"bob"` and `"steve"`.

In this for loop

```
for (int c = 0, n = strlen(b); c < n; c++)
{
    a[c] = b[c];
    //...
```

you are trying to change a string literal. Any attempt to change a string literal results in undefined behavior. Moreover within the if statement

```
    if (a[c] == '\0')
    {
        a[c+1] = '\0';
        a[c] = b[c];
    }
```

you are trying even to write in memory outside the string literal.

From the C Standard (6.4.5 String literals)

> 7 It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
> elements have the appropriate values. **If the program attempts to
> modify such an array, the behavior is undefined.**

Instead of pointers to string literals you need to declare at least one character array where a string literal will be copied.

For example you could write

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char b[] = "steve";
    char a[sizeof( b )] = "bob";

    for ( size_t i = 0; ( a[i] = b[i] ) != '\0'; );

    puts( a );
}
```