Unable to access environ variable once the local variable is put into the environ list
This is my code
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char *var = "TEST=/usr/home";
  putenv(var);
  cout<<getenv("TEST")<<endl; // This works
  var[0]= 'A'; // Crashes as soon as this runs
  cout<<getenv("AEST")<<endl;
  return 0;
}

Output is
/usr/home
zsh: bus error  ./t

If i understand correctly, this var pointer will become part of environmnet itself, so if i update this variable, the getenv should also give me updated stuff
But instead it crashes in mac.
Results in Macbook = It crashes with bus error
Results in Linux = No crash and no output as well, seems like that line is completely just ignored

String literals are const. Surprised this compiles without at least a big warning with a C++ compiler. Use char var[] = "TEST=/usr/home"; instead.

oh that's why...i didn't know about this...it works now, thanks

Please create an answer or propose a duplicate or delete.

@Yunnosch i upvoted the correct commnet...i do not know how to promote it to an answer
i don't want to delete since its a legit question with a legit answer

Fill the editor field below and click "Post Your Answer". The deleting option is for when somebody proposes a good duplicate and you realise that your question is not new.

there is no editor field (there is edit button) and there is no "Post your answer"
I want to promote that comment to answer, rather than copying that comment and answeing my own question

If you do not see an editor field labeled "Your Answer" beneath which you see a button "Post Your Answer" at the bottom of this page then you have a very different user experience here than I have. Are you on a special device or using an unusual browser? Answering your own question with the core of a comment you got is the right way, just give credit.

I see an "Answer your question" button, and I would need to copy paste the comment, basically answering my own question, which i what i want to avoid, seems pretty unnecessary

On the search for a duplicate I only found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal , in my opinion it explains the problem exactly. It is however C, not C++. Does anybody see a C++ duplicate to the same effect?

Oh I see. I was not aware of the difference between own question and others question. Thanks for letting me know (seriously, no sarcasm intended). Still, that difference supports that answering your own question is very much expected. Ideally you flesh the comment out a bit, according to [answer].

Does this answer your question? Modifying String Literal

i pasted the comment and answered my own question, can you upvote that and mark it as answer?

yes, that modifying string literal post answers my question as well

Well done. I do not know however, what you mean by "mark it as answer". It is an answer. You on the other hand might be able to confirm the proposed duplicate. The answer is probably upvotable if you spend some effort towards [answer]. I'd appreciate a C++ version of this, to serve as the duplicate I could not find. However, C++ programmers (which I am not so much....) would probably recommend/prefer using something other than a c-style char array pseudo string.

String literals are const.
Using
char var[] = "TEST=/usr/home";

will work.
